# Geolocation List Sorting using jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, github, geolocation

Found the GeoLocation jQuery Plugin (link below) on GitHub and it works great. My only question is that after 10 addresses are sorted any remaining addresses will come back with a distance unknown. I have 12 address to sort.

I am not sure if this is some default from the Google API or if it is some change that I need to make to file jquery-location.js. It is happening on their demo http://atxwebshow.com/coffeeshops/ too.

**Files** https://github.com/teleject/HTML5-GeoLocation-jQuery-Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Maps API v3 Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is subject to a rate limit and a quota.  If you don't respect that and check for errors, you get about 10 or so results (depends on server load), then you receive OVER_QUERY_LIMIT responses.

Most of the error paths in that plugin cause it to fail silently, although the problem seems to be the geolocation first (if that fails, it won't even attempt the sort), if that succeeds, then you get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT (from the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)). [your code with some error checking](http://www.geocodezip.com/echristo_com_test.html)

Comment: I am just using Google Maps API v3 generated browser key, which has a 25,000 requests/day limit. I am just testing so I know I am not even close to maxing that. My sort is fine (no errors I can see), it just does not grab anything over 10. Sorry first time using Google Maps API.

Comment: Check the error code returned.  The 25,000 requests per day is not relevant, there is a rate limit as well ([search SO for OVER_QUERY_LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-maps-api-3]+OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)).  Please check the returned status (I am not familiar with the plug in, looking at it again, it might be using the DirectionsService, which would have the same issue, is it sorting by straight line distance or driving distance?)

Comment: Would I get an alert box for something like that? My page: http://www.echristo.com/test/test.html

Comment: JS being returned: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/11/16/main.js

Comment: you wrote `Would I get an alert box for something like that?` Nope.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Would paying for Google Maps API for Business help bypass the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT? Cause I have no idea how to clean this code up.